# Passing props to child doesn't make him update - React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, state

I am writing because I can't figure why one of the two childs `Graph.js` won't update after I udpate the state of the parent `Data.js` (throught a "lift up" via the second child `Bouton.js`).

I feel giga dumb and it's been now hours, I'm desperate...

I am trying to display charts with buttons above to choose a period of time for the chart (day, week, month). Clicking the button can change the state of the parent but I can't make the child `Graph` to update. I know I am doing something wrong.

> Parent: Data.js

```
    export default class Data extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { periode: "Jour" };
  }

  handleClick(p) {
    this.setState({
      periode: p
    });
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state);
    return (
      <View>
        <Boutons
          onClick={res => this.handleClick(res)}
          cursor={this.state.periode}
        />
        <Graph periode={this.state.periode} dataType="temp" />
        <Graph periode={this.state.periode} dataType="press" />
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

> Child 1 (everything seems fine)

```
export default class Boutons extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }

  _getNextEntryTime() {
    var d = new Date();
    var h = d.getHours();
    var m = d.getMinutes();
    var res;
    if (m >= 30) {
      res = (h + 1).toString() + ":00";
    } else {
      res = h.toString() + ":30";
    }
    return res;
  }

  //Gestion de la selection des boutons
  _boutonStyle(periode) {
    if (this.props.cursor == periode) {
      return {
        // backgroundColor: "#9c9c9c",
        borderBottomWidth: 3,
        borderColor: "#728FB5",
        width: Dimensions.get("window").width / 3 - 10,
        height: 30,
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "center"
      };
    } else {
      return {
        backgroundColor: "#dfdfdf",
        width: Dimensions.get("window").width / 3 - 10,
        height: 30,
        borderRadius: 2,
        alignItems: "center",
        justifyContent: "center"
      };
    }
  }

  _textStyle(periode) {
    if (this.props.cursor == periode) {
      return { color: "#728FB5" };
    } else {
      return { color: "black" };
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.container_top}>
          <View style={styles.rect}>
            <Text style={styles.text_top}>
              Prochain relevé: {`\n`}
              <Text style={styles.numbers}>{this._getNextEntryTime()}</Text>
            </Text>
          </View>
          <Single />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.container_buttons}>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={this._boutonStyle("Jour")}
            onPress={() => this.props.onClick("Jour")}
          >
            <Text style={this._textStyle("Jour")}>Jour</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={this._boutonStyle("Semaine")}
            onPress={() => this.props.onClick("Semaine")}
          >
            <Text style={this._textStyle("Semaine")}>Semaine</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
          <TouchableOpacity
            style={this._boutonStyle("Mois")}
            onPress={() => this.props.onClick("Mois")}
          >
            <Text style={this._textStyle("Mois")}>Mois</Text>
          </TouchableOpacity>
        </View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

> Graph.js Child 2 that won't update, nothing is happening

```
class Graph extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { isLoading: true, data: [], format_const: null };
  }

  // Chargement de la page et recherche des entrys
  componentDidMount() {
    const entrys = getEntry(this.props.periode);
    entrys.then(reponse => {
      reponse.map(donnee => {
        this.setState({
          data: this.state.data.concat(donnee[this.props.dataType])
        });
      });
      this.setState({
        format_const: Config.CHART[this.props.dataType],
        isLoading: false
      });
    });
  }

  // Affichage du loading
  _displayLoading() {
    if (this.state.isLoading) {
      return (
        <View style={styles.loading_container}>
          <ActivityIndicator size="large" />
        </View>
      );
    }
  }

  _displayChart() {
    return (
      <LineChart
        data={{
          datasets: [
            {
              data: this.state.data,
              strokeWidth: 2 // optional
            }
          ],
          legend: [this.state.format_const["label"]]
        }}
        width={Dimensions.get("window").width - 10} // from react-native
        height={220}
        withInnerLines={false}
        yAxisSuffix={this.state.format_const["alert"]}
        onDataPointClick={({ value, dataset, getColor }) =>
          Alert.alert(`${value}` + this.state.format_const["alert"])
        }
        chartConfig={{
          backgroundGradientFrom: this.state.format_const["color"],
          backgroundGradientTo: this.state.format_const["color"],
          decimalPlaces: 0, // optional, defaults to 2dp
          color: (opacity = 1) => `rgba(255, 255, 255, ${opacity})`,
          style: {
            borderRadius: 16
          },
          propsForDots: {
            r: "2"
          }
        }}
        bezier
        style={{
          marginVertical: 10,
          borderRadius: 16
        }}
      />
    );
  }

  render() {
    if (!this.state.isLoading) {
      return <View>{this._displayChart()}</View>;
    } else {
      return <View>{this._displayLoading()}</View>;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried to create your project locally to trace down the issue, but there are a lot of missing classes and methods. Anyway, have you tried to use `componentDidUpdate() is invoked immediately after updating occurs. This method is not called for the initial render.` instead in Graph.js ?

Comment: if you upload your project into https://codesandbox.io I might be able to help you

Comment: Thanks for your help, indeed ComponentDidUpdate() did the trick !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that your only use of the prop `periode` is in the `componentDidMount` method of `Graph`.  So at mount time, `Graph` reads what the prop is, and then sets the state, which is used in the `Graph` render method.  But when the parent component changes its state, and the new value for `this.state.periode` is passed as a prop to `Graph`, `Graph` doesnt doesn't necessarily know what to do with this updated information.  So you'll need to use a `componentDidUpdate` statement to read new props coming in from the parent's state:

```js
componentDidUpdate(prevProps){

  if (prevProps.periode !== this.props.periode){

      const entrys = getEntry(this.props.periode);
        entrys.then(reponse => {
          reponse.map(donnee => {
            this.setState({
              data: this.state.data.concat(donnee[this.props.dataType])
            });
          });
        });

  }

}

I'm assuming you want the same thing to happen in `componentDidMount` as is happening in `componentDidUpdate`, but you may need to change the code within `componentDidUpdate` to whatever you need.
```

Comment: Thank you so much ! Indeed this was the thing missing (I had to setState to my initial state at the beginning of ComponentDidUpdate and change state.isLoading). But it is finally working !